# TableView Data Overriding Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am using StoryBoard in my application and I have a tableviewcontroller embedded in a navigation controller.

[image]

When I don't load data into the tableview the navigation bar displays correctly but when I load data into the tableview the navigation bar disappears and the tableview extends the full screen. Any reason this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you define heigh header section? :

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 44.0;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, it creates a transparent header but the navigation bar still vanishes.

Comment: You remember to init your navigationBar? If yes try also make this to not hide, so: [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];